# Is this hydrodynamics question solvable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

**The problem**

When studying for an exam, I came across the following exercise (ignore the Portuguese; it's not relevant):

> [image: 1]
>
> Which basically states that the streamline indicated with a darker blue starts at height $y_1 = 271 \;\text{m}$, then passes through point 2 with diameter $d_1 = 100 \;\text{cm}$ with altitude $y_2 = 204$ and goes all the way to point 3, with a tube with diameter $d_2 = 50 \;\text{cm}$ and altitude $0$. The problem asks the velocity with which the fluid ($\rho = 1 \;\mathrm{kg/m^3}$) flows at point 3.

**My thoughts**

It is clear that equation of continuity and Bernoulli's equation come into play in any potential solution. However, I have two complaints on the solvability of this problem:

1. Bernoulli's equation on the three points at the indicated streamline gives:
   $$
   P_1 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_1^2 + 271g\rho = P_2 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_2^2 + 204g\rho = P_3 + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_3^2
   $$

After some thought, I noticed that I couldn't relate $P_2$ to the other variables. For example, in other situations in which  point $2$ has contact with the exterior, we can affirm that $P_1 = P_2 = p_0$ (atmospheric pressure). This is not the case, though, and it is not clear to me how I can express $P_2$ in terms of the other variables.

2. Continuity equation cannot (in principle) be used at point $1$. This is simply because the transversal area of the fluid at that point is not specified. So, $v_1$ appears only in Bernoulli's equation.

Comment: What is $x_i$ ?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to make clear that $v_1$ refers to point $1$, $P_3$ refers to point $3$, and so on. That's why I used two symbols, $x$ being the variable in question (velocity, pressure) and $i$ being the point or place

Comment: P2 is not equal to P1 (atmospheric).  P2 is at a greater depth than P1, which would tend to increase the pressure while the streamlines approaching the cross section at point 2 are converging, which would tend to decrease the pressure at point 2 (as the velocity increases).

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a huge lake. Without knowing the surface area of the lake, you can't apply the equation of continuity at all. But if you consider this as a huge lake as I said, you can neglect the decrease of the water level. That allows you to take $v_1=0$. Also then there is no need to worry about point 2 and its pressure($P_2$). You can directly apply Bernoulli's equation to point 1 and 3.

Comment: Ok, how about $P_3$? We dont know pressure at that point.

Comment: alexp9, Point 3 is disclosed to the outer atmosphere. So $P_3$ is equal to $P_{\text{atm}}$. That is the usual method we solve this type of questions.

Comment: That is an assumption you added. In fact, I agree with you that if it were the case, then its done. But unfortunately the problem does not give that information

Comment: No @alexp9, taking $P_{\text{atm}}$ as $P_3$ is not an assumption. Just look at your image. And as I said before, this is the usual method. Moreover, Bernoulli's equation is based on too many assumptions. If you are interested just have a read of this:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652782/conditions-of-bernoullis-equation-do-they-matter

Comment: I understand the graph makes you thing $P_3 = 1atm$, however, the way the original problem is stated says that that liquid goes directly to a turbine. That's why I didn't add that information. I also acknowledge the usual way things are done, however I don't consider that to be an argument to validate some piece of logic

Comment: @alexp9, What exam is this? The answer depends on what your examiners want. And I don't think the turbine is covered with water.

Comment: This is from past papers on Fluid Dynamics. I mean, It is possible just to accept that such assumption must be made, it is just that I find it odd. I will reflect upon that fact and give your answer as correct if no other better explanation is given

Comment: I guess if they are past papers, you have the answers as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Unless you know how much the turbine restricts the rate of flow, you can only assume that $P_3$ is one atmosphere.